# facing an error "system problem detected error", while installing ubuntu

Tags: dual-boot, system-installation

i am installing ubuntu, but while installing it is raising an error "system problem detected error" and then it says installation failed. i have done it many time, facing same error each time. my secure boot is disabled, I have tried both version ubuntu 22.04.2 & 23.04. i am using acer nitro 5 8 GB RAM & SSD 512 GB.  what is this problem , why it is raising and what is its solution.

Comment: You've not said what Ubuntu product & thus ISOs you were using (Ubuntu has various products for a release, and some choices of ISO; eg. Ubuntu 22.04 LTS Server uses the `subiquity` installer; Ubuntu 22.04 LTS Desktop uses `ubiquity` installer, Ubuntu 23.04 Desktop has two installer choices selected by ISO used (`ubuntu-desktop-installer` OR `ubiquity`); Ubuntu 23.04 Server uses `subiquity` , and I've not mentioned *flavors* (that use `ubiquity` or `calamares`).  ie. You've not said which you tried, used or the actual error.  Please elaborate.

Answer (score 0):

You used the desktop version right to install. I also did that. I booted from USB and pressed install. My theory is to clean restart the ssd/hdd then try installing it. Might just work.